# New dynamic group AzureAD powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make a dynamic group in AzureADMS, but I get the error message *"A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'MembershipRule'."* This is my command:

```
New-AzureADMSGroup `
    -DisplayName "IT"`
    -Description "IT-department" `
    -MailEnabled $False `
    -SecurityEnabled $True `
    -MailNickName "IT" `
    -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" `
    -MembershipRule "user.department -eq "IT"" `
    -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

Could you please help?

Other inputs are also welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use the preview version of this cmdlet yet you have installed only [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) (not [AzureAD Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview))

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have installed and imported the AzureADPreview module

Comment: The error message is clear, `-MembershipRule` is not a parameter existing in the `2.0` version of that cmdlet, but exists in `2.0-preview`. Is the only explanation for what you're facing

Comment: Okay thank you. How do I check which version I have? I am able to do the Import-Module AzureADPreview without errors.

Comment: What do you see when you do `(Get-Module AzureADPreview).Version` ? should be `2.0.2.149`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduced in my environment and got similar error.***

[image]

The error occurs as you may have had  incorrect  module AzureAD.
So I uninstall Azure AD module and install AzureADPreview by running this command

```
 Uninstall-module AzureAD
```

Instead of Azure AD used AzureADPreview

```
Install-module AzureADPreview
```

[image]

After installed AzureADPreview, I runned your commands and got an output Successfully.

[image]

***Portal:***
[image]

***Reference:***
[New-AzureADMSGroup (AzureADPreview) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0-preview)